# How to store ids with mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a user model and user references_many folders. I want to add a field where current user can store ids of other users folders. What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on the mongoid site says you should `references_many :preferences, :stored_as => :array, :inverse_of => :people` but in recent mongoid builds this is not available. Instead, you should use references_and_referenced_in_many.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  references_and_referenced_in_many :favorite_folders, :class_name=>'Folder'
end
```

This will create an field of folder_id, :type=>Array and will store the array of the object

```
user = User.new
other_user = User.first
user.favorite_folders << other_user.folders.first #assuming this exists
user.save
```

Comment: I already have folders field in my user model. references_many folders. How  to handle this?

Comment: Edited the answer to have a user with favorite_folders... rename as necessary.